# Vim markdown folding disappears

Tags: vim

Recently, when I open a file, most likely the issue is limited to `rmarkdown` filetype (folding provided by `vim-pandoc` plugin; I am using terminal vim 8.2 in Linux). After working on the file for a while, the folding disappears. The folding keys (`zi`, `zM`) and `set foldenable` does not have any effect, defining a different `foldmethod` does not help. Accordingly, `set foldlevel` reports `0` everywhere. The only way to get folds back is to close the file and reopen it.

How could I troubleshoot it to figure out what goes wrong? How could I get the folds back without closing/reopening the file?

Comment: Do you have `set foldenable` in your `.vimrc` file?

Comment: Also, if you are using ftplugin, do any of your file types unset foldenable?

Comment: We will need something more specific than "After working on the file for a while, the folding disappears.". Does it also happen with other filetypes? Is your Markdown folding provided by a third-party plugin? Folding is not a feature that comes and goes.

Comment: @N.Kern, I have defined `foldmethod in `.vimrc` but no `foldenable`. I will try if it helps, but I have `vim-pandoc` installed, I think this takes over when I open a `rmarkdown` file.

Comment: @romainl, fair enough. This is why I asked for help to figure out what might go wrong (not only to fix it). I don't know vim enough to interrogate the situation in an ill-behaved session. I am almost sure folding is provided by `vim-pandoc` (will try to figure out if that is indeed the case). I work almost exclusively on `rmarkdown` files, and for extended periods of time, so I am much less confident in making a claim about other filetypes, but I'd say the issue is limited to `rmarkdown` files.

Comment: @romainl, I edited the post according to your suggestions

Comment: what is the current `foldmethod` what is `fdn`?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo: `foldmethod=expr` and `fdn=20`.

Comment: Are this the values once it is stuck? If so have a look at your foldexpression `set foldexpr?` and start debugging.

Comment: Thanks, @DoktorOSwaldo, this helped me to find a solution though I still don't know the exact cause nor how to stop it from happening.

Answer (score 1):

Troubleshooting: while having `foldmethod=expr`, `set foldexpr?` told me it is indeed `vim-pandoc` doing the folding and the `vim-pandoc` documentation tells how to change the folding mode on the fly.

Fixing without reopening the file: issue a vim command `PandocFolding='syntax'`. Any of the `syntax|relative|stacked` should make the folding work again. Weird enough, `let g:pandoc#folding#mode='syntax'` did not help.

I still don't know what causes the issue and how to prevent it from happening.

Comment: probably should open an issue at the plugin [github](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc). ALso start vim with just this plugin to make sure it is not an incompatibility